# Reset name attribute array indexes, dynamically add remove rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have to post data via ajax and need the name attribute array indexes to reset.

For example:

1st row:

```
<select data-placeholder="Colours" class="colours chosen-select" 
multiple tabindex="4" name="colours[0][]">
<option value="">Red</option>
<option value="">Orange</option>
</select>
```

2nd Row dynamically added:

```
<select data-placeholder="Colours" class="colours chosen-select" 
multiple tabindex="4" name="colours[1][]">
<option value="">Red</option>
<option value="">Orange</option>
</select>
```

The name colours array must increment by 1 everytime I add, as well as reset the values when I remove.

I have looked around but not found any solution.

Here is what I have:

Adding:

```
var tbl = $("#service");
$("#addRowBtn").click(function () {
var count = $('#rowCount tr').length;   

$("<tr>" +    
"<td>" +
"<select data-placeholder=\"Colours\" class=\"colours chosen-select\" 
multiple tabindex=\"4\"\ name=\"colours[" +
count +
"][]\">" +
"<option value=\"\">Red</option>" +
"<option value=\"\">Orange</option>" +
"</select></td>" +
"<td><i style=\"color:#d64830\" class=\"delRowBtn fa fa-minus- 
circle\"></i></td></tr>").appendTo(tbl);
```

Deleting a  row:

```
$(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function () {

  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 });
```

I have added var count to increment the indexes, but I'm not able to reset the values when removing.

Please help!

Comment: Do you want to chnage the names of **all the list** whenever you do an ajax call, or only add one list with name that equals to the previous except the number?

Comment: Which is the purpose to add such name to the select element?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman. I'm not sure of your question?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik It is needed to store an array within the array already posted.

Comment: When you add a new list, do you want that all exisiting list will update with the new  name?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, when I add new row. The indexes will increment by one. When I remove any row all the indexes will reset. Not sure if that answers your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to cycle all select of your table and change the attribute "name" of each select everytime you delete an item.

```
$('#rowCount tr td select').each(function(idx, item){
 $(item).attr("name", "colours[" + idx + "][]")
});
```

**update**

like suggest @ChayimFriedman the cool version of previous suggestion

```
$('#rowCount select').attr('name', function(idx) { return "colours[" + idx + "][]"; });
```

Comment: It works some how. When I added three rows then remove the middle one. It changes the value of the 3rd one to: name="colours[7][]"

Comment: More pretty - `$('#rowCount select').attr('name', function(idx, item) { return "colours[" + idx + "][]"; });`.

Comment: try to change jquery selector $('#rowCount tr td select') with $('#service tbody tr td select'), you can also use the developer tools for a check of the length of your select tag in the dom it's correct with $('#service tbody tr td select').length

Comment: Thank you! it seems to work with: $('.colours').attr('name', function(idx, item) { return "colours[" + idx + "][]"; });

Comment: @mpdev7 See [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function), you can pass to `attr()` a function that will evaulate on every element. If it won't return or will return `undefined`, the previous value won't change.

Comment: A small comment: you can remove the parameter `item` because you don't use it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thank you for your suggestions, i've updated the answer